# Как спрогнозировать значения на n дней? out-of-sample

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Обучил модель предсказывать данные на тестовом наборе данных. Теперь нужно сделать прогноз на n-дней от последней даты в датасете. Как это сделать?

Обучал модель так:

1. Сгенерил новые признаки

```
def make_features(data, max_lag, rolling_mean_size):

    data['day'] = data.index.day
    data['weekday'] = data.index.weekday
    data['dayofyear'] = data.index.dayofyear
    for lag in range(1, max_lag+1):
        data['lag_{}'.format(lag)]= data['events'].shift(lag)
    data['rolling_mean'] = data['events'].shift().rolling(rolling_mean_size).mean()
    data['rolling_std'] = data['events'].rolling(2).std()
    return data
```

2. Разбил на тестовые и тренировочные данные

```
def timeseries_train_test_split(X, y, test_size):
    
    # Получаем индекс, с которого начинаются тестовые данные
    test_index = int(len(X)*(1-test_size))
    
    X_train = X.iloc[:test_index]
    y_train = y.iloc[:test_index]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_index:]
    y_test = y.iloc[test_index:]
    
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

y = data_new.dropna().events
X = data_new.dropna().drop(['events'], axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = timeseries_train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
```

3. Обучил XGboost-ом

```
reg = xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1000,
                       nthread=4,
                       min_child_weight=6,
                       learning_rate=0.1,
                       subsample=0.7,
                       max_depth=11,
                       colsample_bytree=0.7,
                      )

reg.fit(X_train, y_train,
        eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)],
        early_stopping_rounds=50, 
        verbose=False) 
X_test_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
```

В результате получил 2-недельное предсказание по тестовому набору данных
https://skr.sh/sBimjbd3ITY?a

Comment: А у вас временные ряды или обычные фичи? Без детализации непонятно, что советовать, случаи бывают разные.

Comment: @CrazyElf Временные ряды, с генерацией доп.фич для предсказания. Выглядит это примерно так: https://skr.sh/sBi853ZAHkQ?a. В изначальном датасете есть только date и events.

Comment: здравствуйте. заметил что моя задача немного похоже на вашу, схемтически, можете пожалуйста с моей проблемой помочь?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1565580/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-xgboost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это задача на временные ряды, то предсказывать нужно пошагово:

1. делаете фичи из имеющихся у вас данных
2. предсказываете на день вперёд за край имеющихся данных
3. добавляете полученное предсказание в ваши данные
4. если ещё не все `n` дней предсказали, то переходите к п.1

Конечно, при таком методе предсказания степень неопределённости сильно растёт с каждым шагом. Если сначала вы опирались на реальные данные, то с каждым последующим шагом вы всё больше начинаете опираться на ваши же предсказания. Поэтому предсказание временных рядов без чёткой периодичности и без дополнительных каких-то данных - дело довольно рисковое.

**Update:** Как собственно предсказывать.

- делаете новый датафрейм с индексом - следующей датой за максимальной, имеющейся в X, добавляете его через `concat` к собственно `X` в конец
- запускаете `make_features` на этом обновлённом `X`, таким образом заполняете фичи везде, включая последнюю строку датафрейма
- берёте последнюю строку с уже заполненными теперь фичами `X_pred = X.iloc[[-1]]`
- получаете предсказание `y_pred = reg.predict(X_pred)`
- дальше можете заполнить `X['events'] = y_pred[0]`
- и перейти к предсказанию следующей даты

Comment: А как технически реализовать пункт 2?

Comment: @spacenew А как вы обучали модель на тестовых данных? Давайте уже ваш код хотя бы схематически. Вы же обучали модель предсказанию данных на дату в будущем?

Comment: Предсказанию в будущее не обучал. Добавил в описание процесс обучения

Comment: @spacenew Дописал ответ